# R ggplot2 plot single data with 2 hlines and correct legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

With the help of Axeman I have been able to plot one datum with mean/median hlines. To complete the annotation I want to put the mean/median values into the legend labels. My code:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
wf <- data.table::fread('Date Gals Days  GpD    GpM
                     2016-10-21  6.0    1  6.0  186.0
                     2016-10-22  6.0    1  6.0  186.0
                     2016-10-23 12.4    1 12.4  384.4
                     2016-10-24 26.8    1 26.8  830.8
                     2016-10-25 33.3    1 33.3 1032.3
                     2016-10-26 28.3    1 28.3  877.3')
nmu <- mean(wf$Gals)
textmu <- paste("Mean:", round(nmu, 2))
nmed <- median(wf$Gals)
textmed <- paste("Median:", round(nmed, 2))

p <- ggplot(wf, aes(Date, Gals)) +  
     geom_line(aes(lty = "Gals", color = "Gals", group = 1)) +
     geom_hline(aes(yintercept = nmu,  linetype = textmu, color = textmu), 
                color='red',size=1)+
     geom_hline(aes(yintercept = nmed, linetype = textmed, color = textmed), 
                color='orange',size=1)+
     #scale_linetype('Water Usage') +
     scale_color_manual('Water Usage', 
                        values=c('Gals'='black',textmu='red', textmed='orange')) +
     xlab("") + 
     ylab("Gallons per Day")

print(p)
```

Produces:
[image]

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a vector of labels, then use the code that I gave in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032917/r-ggplot2-single-line-plot-with-2-hlines-legends):

```
labels <- c(Gals = 'Gals',
            Mean = paste("Mean:", round(mean(wf$Gals), 2)),
            Median = paste("Median:", round(median(wf$Gals), 2)))

ggplot(wf, aes(Date, Gals)) +  
  geom_line(aes(lty = "Gals", color = "Gals", group = 1)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(wf$Gals), linetype = "Mean", color = "Mean"), size=1) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median(wf$Gals), linetype = "Median", color = "Median"), size = 1) +
  scale_linetype('Water Usage', labels = labels) +
  scale_color_manual(
    'Water Usage', 
    values = c('Gals' = 'black', 'Mean' = 'red', 'Median' = 'orange'),
    labels = labels
  ) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Gallons per Day")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice result. This is precisely what I wanted to do, keeping  the  data.frame as simple as possible and picking up a few more pieces of ggplot2 knowledge.Thanks to Axeman and the community!

Answer (score 0):

by melting your `data.table` you can:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
wf <- data.table::fread('Date Gals Days  GpD    GpM
                    2016-10-21  6.0    1  6.0  186.0
                    2016-10-22  6.0    1  6.0  186.0
                    2016-10-23 12.4    1 12.4  384.4
                    2016-10-24 26.8    1 26.8  830.8
                    2016-10-25 33.3    1 33.3 1032.3
                    2016-10-26 28.3    1 28.3  877.3')

wf[,`:=`(Mean=round(mean(Gals),2),Median=round(median(Gals),2))]

p <- ggplot(melt(wf,id.vars = c(1,3))
[variable%in%c("Gals","Mean","Median")], aes(Date, 
value,color=variable,group=variable)) +  
geom_line() +
scale_color_manual('Water Usage',values=c('Gals'='black',Mean='red', 
Median='orange')) +
xlab("") + 
ylab("Gallons per Day")

print(p)
```

Comment: This does not put the mean and median values in the legend labels, as per the question.